# How to fix "Trailing/Leading spaces" error in commits previous to HEAD?

Tags: git, github

Apologies up front, I'm an aspiring git guru, but not quite there yet...

I currently have 5 local commits that have not yet been pushed to my remote branch; the first 2 are prohibiting me from pushing because they have **trailing/Leading spaces errors** in some of the source files.

**When I tried to push...**

`$ git push -u origin my-branch`

**I received the following error...**

```
$ git push -u origin my-branch
Counting objects: 124, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (122/122), done.
Writing objects: 100% (124/124), 23.19 KiB | 3.31 MiB/s, done.
Total 124 (delta 94), reused 2 (delta 2)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (94/94), completed with 16 local objects.
remote: bin/pre_receive_hook: failed with exit status 1
remote: Starting pre_receive_hook.rb at 02:30:52.384
remote: Updating refs/heads/my-branch from 89e1e6deeec412a914c4cfc4c6dec101b15ba4c5 to 0cd270067efecff743505d6613c2cff07a4f7f14
remote: Running Conventions Check...
remote: Starting ConventionCheck at 02:30:53.162
remote: Checking Commit 0cd270067: OB-221 Remove pry bindings left in spec, remove leading/trailing spaces in files, add newline to end of files
remote: Checking Commit 1342336cd: OB-221 Remove pry bindings left in spec
remote: Checking Commit 7dc993531: OB-221 Refactored SoapRequest and CalculateInvoiceTaxRequest to accomodate a more traditional Adapter pattern
remote:     Trailing/Leading spaces error, use --check in your diff to see the problem: Conventions
To github.my-site.com:my-site/argh_express.git
 ! [remote rejected]         OB-221-taxware-api-adapter -> OB-221-taxware-api-adapter (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.my-site.com:on-site/argh_express.git'
```

**I've narrowed the trailing/leading spaces errors to source files committed to first two (2) commits using**

`$ git diff --check -R 7dc993531 bbfd2723d`

**Which produced the following output (trailing whitespace represented by \b)**

```
ROOT/rails/app/models/integration/tax_ware/calculate_invoice_tax_result_model.rb:100: trailing whitespace.
+\b\b\b\b\b\b\b
ROOT/rails/spec/models/integration/tax_ware/soap_request_spec.rb:17: trailing whitespace.
+\b\b
ROOT/rails/spec/models/integration/tax_ware/soap_request_spec.rb:18: trailing whitespace.
+  let(:soap_request) do\b
```

**So the commits in error are the following (marked in bold)**

- 0cd270067
- 1342336cd
- 7dc993531
- **9ca4f853f** <<< Trailing whitespace
- **bbfd2723d** <<< Trailing whitespace

**I basically want to either**

1. fix those source files (which doesn't quite make sense to me because the files have changed with more recent comments) or
2. somehow just push the most recent commit (0cd270067)

**However, the most recent commit doesn't contain ALL the files that need to be pushed!** How do I go about pushing the most recent local commit, include ALL the files I need, and discard all the previous local commits?

Comment: *Every* commit contains *every* file. `git show` or `git diff` just *compares* two commits, so that it can tell what changed between them. The `git push` command pushes the commits; that's why your remote Git's "check commits before we accept them" checked multiple commits.

Comment: @torek I didn't know that every commit contains every file, but I do know about diff and push and I understand why this is happening. So I can push the most recent commit and discard the previous commits based on what you're saying. The problem now is how to do that and disregard the previous commits. What about git reset --hard HEAD? Will this disregard the previous commits and will it have any effect at all because I'm already pointing to HEAD?

Comment: I don't have time to write this up properly here. You can either collapse the series of commits down to a single different commit (`git rebase -i` and change `pick` to `squash` on all but the first one) and then fix up the final commit; or you can use `git rebase -i` and choose `edit` on individual commits, to let you make changes and continue cherry-picking each individual commit to assemble a final sequence of new-and-improved commits.

Comment: @torek *"Every commit contains every file"* that is simply wrong. In that case your git history would have the size of your working directory multiplied with the count of all commits in your history. But `git` commits rather  contain *all **changes** on any (tracked) file*. When you checkout git simply undoes/redoes this changes.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle There are 2 strategies in version control — snapshots (store files) and diffs. Git uses snapshots strategy; every commit has a pointer to a tree which has pointers to subtrees and blobs (files). Git employs clever algorithms to avoid storing copies of identical files but torek is absolutely right — every commit contains the entire tree.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: it's true that behind the scenes, Git will "pack" similar objects (into pack files), and use delta-compression within the pack files. But each commit just has objects, and logically, objects are independent of each other. Each commit has a top level tree that contains all the files of that commit. Try `git ls-tree -r HEAD` and `git show <commit-hash>:`, for instance. Most VCSes do delta-compression at the front end instead of the back end. Git is different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, where you just want to have the current changes on a new commit and haven't previously pushed any of the commits, an interactive rebase is actually overkill. The easiest method is to perform a soft reset back to the previous version and make a new commit:

```
git reset --soft bbfd2723d^
```

This will move the head back before you made your commits, but leave your working directory and index unchanged. Then you can build your new commit(s) as you would normally.

For reference, this method is described in the git book chapter [7.7](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified#_squashing_2).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to discard older comments and push just the latest commit singularly, `git rebase -I` will help you.

```
# activate `git rebase` on the last 5 commits on your branch
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

You now have the following choices (apart from `pick` and `reword`):

- `edit`: make changes to the commit individually
- `squash`: flatten the commit into the previous commit, but merge the two commit messages as a single commit message
- `fixup`: flatten the commit into the previous but discard the current commit message

If you want to keep a record of the 5 commit messages, choose `squash` else `fixup` like in the example below:

```
pick  bbfd2723d
fixup 9ca4f853f
fixup 7dc993531
fixup 1342336cd
fixup 0cd270067
```

- note that the commits are in reverse here..
- `pick` the *oldest* commit you want to adjust and `squash / fixup` the subsequent commits.
- You may want to choose `reword` instead of `pick` on the oldest commit so that the final commit message mirrors the final diff.
- the result will leave you with a single unpushed commit with a different SHA entirely and since you say the whitespace issues have been resolved in the newer commits, the final commit will be one single clean *pushable* commit